# R file deleted from Android Studio

Tags: java, android, http

R file is suddenly deleted from my package and all the R symbols in the all activities cant be resolved, how could I restore R file ?

Comment: do a project rebuild

Comment: Some of your xml files may contain a small error. Or you are using invalid characters in your resource file names.

Answer (score 1):

Rebuild your project!

`R.java` is an auto-generated file that **contains resource IDs for all the resources of `res/` directory.**

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html

Answer (score 1):

Or try to "clean" your project. In Android Studio, you click Build > Clean Project. I'm not sure why this is different than just rebuilding, but it usually does the trick for me when I have that same thing happen.

Answer (score 0):

check res/ directory. Can be caused by xml file.

Comment: This has always been my issue in Android Studio. Please make your answer more of an answer, please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. Most of the time it is in the `strings.xml`, `styles.xml` and of course the `AndroidManfest.xml`.